# An irb-type tool for C/C++

Tags: c, ruby

When writing ruby code, it is easy to test how different functions behave by testing them out in irb. But to test code in C, I usually have to open up a separate IDE and write code there to test how it works. Is there an interpreter-like tool available in Unix or   Windows platform?

Answer (score 1):

C is not an interpreted language. However, there are a couple interpreters. I think the best one is Ch however it is not open source. CINT is open source:

http://directory.fsf.org/project/CINT/

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to test a copy & paste-able bit of code, I often use [CodePad](http://codepad.org/) to see the results of single functions immediately without compiling.  It has its limits, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Ch](http://www.softintegration.com/) is the closest you'll get to a C/C++ REPL. I believe it supports all features of C and some of C++.