# Is there anything like IRB for C?

Tags: c, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An irb-type tool for C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442105/an-irb-type-tool-for-c-c)

I'm working on some C extensions, and I miss being able to test code interactively.

Comment: You could google for read-eval-print-loop or REPL

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775674/is-it-possible-to-build-a-interactive-c-shell/3775691#3775691).

Answer (score 4):

The closest you'll get is `gdb`, [which can be used as an almost REPL for C](http://blog.pclewis.com/2010/03/tip-using-gdb-as-an-interactive-c-shell/).

Example from the article:

```
~% gdb ./test
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048452
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/pcl/sandbox/test
Breakpoint 1, 0x08048452 in main ()
(gdb) set $a = malloc(1234)
(gdb) call sprintf($a, "Hello %d", 12345*12345*12345)
$1 = 15
(gdb) print (char*)$a
$2 = 0x96c6008 "Hello 170287977"
(gdb) print (unsigned int)atoi("-1")
$3 = 4294967295
(gdb) print (unsigned int)atoi("4294967295")
$4 = 2147483647
```

To get a better idea of everything that's possible and not in gdb, [take a look at the manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) and [this refcard](http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy255/refcards/gdb-refcard.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

See this other question: [Is it possible to build a interactive C shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775674/is-it-possible-to-build-a-interactive-c-shell)

Another, more generic, tool I like is [hsandbox](http://niemeyer.net/hsandbox), though is not *really* interactive.